# Delete S3 bucket versions with delete marker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scripting, storage, bucket

I am trying to delete an s3 bucket with versions and delete markers.
I cannot delete them from the console and I am stuck on this for a while.

I have also tried running a few python scripts but still nothing changes.

Comment: [A script to delete all objects, versions and delete markers from an s3 bucket.](https://gist.github.com/seventhskye/0cc7b2804252975d36dca047ab7729e9)

Answer (score 0):

In the Amazon S3 management console, you will see: `Versions: Hide / Show`

Clicking `Show` will display all versions of an object, including the Delete Marker. You can then select versions and delete markers and delete them.

Comment: they are not deleting directly from the console

Comment: When you select a Delete Marker in the console, and then choose Delete, what happens?

Comment: It just stays there as it is and does not delete. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: That is strange. I wonder whether you have sufficient permissions to delete versions and delete markers?

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code should do what you want:

```py
bucket = "my_s3_bucket_1234aefa"
file_to_delete = "file_i_want_to_delete.png"
results = []
response = s3_client.list_object_versions(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Prefix=file_to_delete,
)
for k in ['Versions', 'DeleteMarkers']:
    if k in response:
        k_response = response[k]
        to_delete = [r['VersionId'] for r in k_response if r['Key'] == file_to_delete]
        results.extend(to_delete)
for version in results:
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_to_delete, VersionId=version)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this code just delete the delete markers themselves, and not the underlying version that is still there?

Comment: @AmundeepSingh it should delete every version of every file, along with every delete marker.